# Create a shortcut to always run as administrator

Tags: windows, windows-10, shortcuts, administrator

I'm using a certain application on my Windows 10 which I always need to run as administrator. I pinned a shortcut for it to my taskbar so every time I need to run it I just right click the shortcut, right click the application, and click `Run as administrator`.

The question is: Is there a way in Windows 10 to create a shortcut which runs as administrator by default? So that I just left click it once to run it as administrator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click the icon on your Task Bar.
Then right click on the application name again if the "close/unpin/..." menu opens.
Then select `"Properties"` -> `"Advanced"` -> and select `"Run as administrator"`

Guide with screenshots: http://www.guidingtech.com/4862/always-run-as-administrator/

Comment: Thank you. For Windows 10 version 10.0.18362 is: 
`Properties -> Shortcut -> Advanced -> Run as administrator`